# Is this statement true on norming?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let us call a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a norm if:

1. $f(v)\geq0$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n.$
2. $f(v)=0\implies v=0.$
3. $f(v+w)\leq f(v)+f(w)$ for all $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n.$
4. $f(\lambda v)=|\lambda| f(v)$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}.$

With this definition, is it true that if $v=(v_1,...,v_n)$, then $\frac{v_i}{f(v)}\leq1$ for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}?$
If possible, can you link a proof/counterexample?

Comment: In number 3, did you mean $f(v+w) \leq f(v) + f(w)$?

Comment: Consider that if $f$ is a norm, then so is $(1/2)f$.

Comment: @NazimJ yes, thank you for the spot, you are right.

Comment: @DavidMitra thank you, I will try the proof that way.